# Android Dependency Injection on Intent with Dagger2

Tags: android, android-intent, dagger-2

I learn about Dagger2 DI in my android code, and in my activity, I create an Intent to call the Phone Activity, I wondering is it possible to inject the Intent Class in my activity? so I dont need to use Intent intent = new Intent() like this code :

```
Intent call=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + textView.getText().toString()));
    startActivity(call);
```

Can I inject the intent like I inject the presenter?

```
@Inject
DetailScreenPresenter detailScreenPresenter;
```

Thank you very much for answering

Comment: What advantage do you hope to obtain by injecting the intent?

Comment: to keep the Activity Class independent, maybe? so it is not possible?

Comment: It's certainly possible.  I'm trying to understand whether you have a specific reason for wanting to do this, such as testing with a mock intent action, or you're just idealistically trying to eliminate uses of `new`.

Answer (score 0):

You should just inject the instantiated Intent and set the rest yourself. You *should not* inject services or activities that perform an action before they're already injected, it's bad code design and certainly makes it difficult to debug.

To inject, make sure that you annotate the method in the module with `@Provides` and make sure that you *don't annotate with* `@singleton`. This will return a *new instance* every time you inject.

```
public class IntentDialer extends Intent {

    public IntentDialier() {
        super(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        ...
    }
}

@Module
public class ProviderModule {

    @Provides
    IntentDialer provideIntentDialer() {
        return new IntentDialer();
    }
}

intentDialer.setData(myUrl.toString());
doSomething(intentDialer);
```